# Getting multiple logged in user in Firebase API for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to automatically login user if he has already registered. Problem is when I do getCurrentUser it returns with multiple Users even though my user is registered with Facebook only. I cannot figure out why it is showing the first user. This is my code for authStateListner in the launching activity:

```
mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            int i = 0;
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user == null){
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
                return;
            }
                for(UserInfo info : firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderData()){
                    Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG, "" + i++);
                    if(info == null){
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);
                    }


                    if(info.getProviderId().contentEquals("google.com")){
                        Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG,info.getProviderId());
                        Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG,"Official Login" + info.getEmail());
                        Intent officialIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, OfficialActivity.class);
                        officialIntent.putExtra("emailId",info.getEmail());
                        startActivity(officialIntent);
                    }else if(info.getProviderId().contentEquals("facebook.com")){
                        Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG,info.getProviderId());
                        Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG,"Resident Login through fb");
                        Intent reportIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
                        reportIntent.putExtra("resident_id", info.getEmail());
                        startActivity(reportIntent);
                    }else{
                        Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG,info.getProviderId());
                        Log.d(START_ACTIVITY_TAG,"Resident Login normal" + info.getEmail());
                        Intent reportIntent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
                        reportIntent.putExtra("resident_id",info.getEmail());
                        startActivity(reportIntent);
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

My Logs for this code block are as follows:

> ```
> D/Start_Activity: firebase
> D/Start_Activity: Resident Login normalnull
> D/Start_Activity: 1
> D/Start_Activity: facebook.com
> D/Start_Activity: Resident Login through fb
> D/Start_Activity: 0
> D/Start_Activity: firebase
> D/Start_Activity: Resident Login normalnull
> D/Start_Activity: 1
> D/Start_Activity: facebook.com
> D/Start_Activity: Resident Login through fb
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The output looks as expected to me.

The first output shows the UserInfo that Firebase internally created. The second output then shows the provider data gotten from Facebook.